# WordPress Ajax call can't get binary data, it returns <?php only

Tags: ajax, wordpress, download, binary

Well, I can get Ajax call return binary data such as image without WordPress. But I just can't get it works in WordPress. It returns <?php and nothing else. Before I go to read through WordPress ajax-admin.php source code to find out what is going on there, I think I'd better ask here to see if I hit a known issue and any workaround already here.

my working code without WordPress
PHP code

```
get_image();
function get_image(){   
    $file='Large-Sample-Image-download-for-Testing.jpg';
    //make it downloadable
    header("content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.jpg");
    header('cache-control: must-revalidate');
    header("expires: 0");            
    //return file contents
    readfile($file);
}
```

HTML code which give Ajax call to above PHP piece

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $("#ajax_get_image_button").click(function() {        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST','get_image.php', true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob"; 
        xhr.onload = function() {
            //console.log(this.response);
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src=URL.createObjectURL(this.response); 
            document.body.append(img);
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="ajax_get_image_button" name="ajax_get_image_button" value="Ajax call to get image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Let us go into WordPress...
HTML part

```
<div><input type="button" name="ajax_get_image_button" id="ajax_get_image_button" value="Ajax call to get image"  class="button-primary"/>
```

JS part

```
    $("#ajax_get_image_button").click(function() {        
        var data = {                    
                _ajax_nonce: my_js_obj.nonce, 
                action: "func_get_image",
            };
        url=my_js_obj.ajax_url;
        //xhr
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src=URL.createObjectURL(this.response); 
            document.body.append(img);
        };

        xhr.send($.param( data ));
    });
```

PHP part

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','my_javascript');
function my_javascript($hook) {
    global $current_screen;
    if( $hook !== $current_screen->base ) return; //my page see this script only
        wp_enqueue_script( 
        'my_js', 
        plugins_url( 'js/get_image.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery'), 
        '1.0.0',
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'my_js',
        'my_js_obj',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' ),
            'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'my_nonce' ),
        )
    );

}
...
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_get_image', 'func_get_image' );
function func_get_image(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce');
    get_image();
    wp_die();
}
```

I thought WordPress just hook and execute my script, so it should return result as I expected in regular PHP code. But it doesn't. Tried look up any solution for this issue but seems no match found after couple of days.

Solution

```
readfile(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/'. $file);
```

Comment: Next debugging step: put [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) calls in your various php functions so you know what code is invoked when. Better yet, use a php debugger.

Comment: I figured out now. I got 2 issues. The first one <?php is because I got one PHP file which started with <?php<?php. Once I got this fixed, I quickly realized WordPress require PHP to readfile with full path. It means readfile(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/'. $file); is the key.